# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'laravel'@'172.27.0.7' (using password: YES)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, macos

Principiante en Laravel.

Tengo un problema al querer hacer las migraciones a la base de datos desde laravel me marca el siguiente error:

SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'laravel'@'172.27.0.7' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = devstagram and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

ESTO SOLO CUANDO UTILIZO DOCKER, PORQUE CUANDO NO UTILIZO DOCKER QUE UTILIZO SOLAMENTE PHP SI ME HACE LAS MIGRACIONES CORRECTAMENTE CON LAS MISMAS CREDENCIALES DE MYSQL.

Answer (score 0):

Mira veo que la IP 172.27.0.7 es una IP privada. Por tanto, desde Docker no puede ser lo mismo. En Docker usas docker-composer y allí puedes crear una dependencia entre los dos dockers(WEB+MYSQL) usando **depends_on:**

Una vez ya está creado, desde el docker web se conoce mysql por su nombre(vez de la IP poner nombre de mysql)

Te pongo un ejemplo de github
https://github.com/shamith234/Laraval-php8

Comment: Voy a checarlo en el docker muchas gracias Shamith.